# Pixel color labeling tool

Tags: image-segmentation

Anyone know good tool for manual pixel color labeling like [SegNet](http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/projects/segnet/) do?

Answer (score 1):

LableMe does same work as SegNet but manually. You can learn about this tool from [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdZJROsQ5xk)

To start using this tool you have to [create an account](http://labelme2.csail.mit.edu/Release3.0/index.php) on LabelMe website.

Answer (score 1):

You could try DataTurks
[  https://dataturks.com/  ], 
Beautiful UI + easy to use + free for open datasets. 
Some sample projects:
https://dataturks.com/projects/trending﻿

Answer (score 0):

There are great tools at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_manual_image_annotation_tools.

I personally had troubles using labelME, the interface is terrible.